# laravel 5.8 access other table's property in one to many relation

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have 3 tables

1. hotel
2. province
3. city

the hotel has a relation to the city and the city has a relation to the province.
city id will save in the city field in the hotel table.
how can I access city name and province name in the Hotel model?

in hotel model I wrote this :

```
  public function city(){
        return $this->belongsTo(City::class);
    }
```

and in the city model I have this:

```
   public function hotel(){
        return $this->hasMany(Hotel::class);
    }


    public function province(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Province::class);
    }
```

and in province

```
  public function cities(){
        return $this->hasMany(City::class);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function provinces()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Province', 'App\City');
}
```

In hotel model and you can access province name by using in the controller like

```
$hotel = Hotel::find(1);
dd($hotel->provinces);
```

and use that variable in the blade

Comment: and how can i access it  in blade template ?

Answer (score 0):

[Has Many Through](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) relationship is what you are looking for.

Comment: by that how can i access them in blade?

Comment: In the same way you access any other Eloquent relationships. With the `->` operator.